# Raspberry Pi won't boot up

Tags: boot, power-supply

When turned on, the TV just says "HDMI 3". My power light is stable (red), and the "ACT" light flashes 4 times, then pauses the 4 times... It says the `start.elf` is not launched, but I can't find a way to launch it.

Please tell me how to launch it or what to do?

Comment: Question. Is the MD5 of the image file good? Sometimes a download hiccups and the file gets slightly corrupted. Not enough to cause a problem when you write the image to the file to the SD card, but enough to cause a problem like what you're saying.

Answer (score 1):

please, try to copy the image to your SD card again, or get another, preferably bigger SD card and try to use it instead. if you see the same problem, then try to redownload the system image once again and this time carefully check the SHA1/MD5 sum of the received file. if still fails, try to download different OS flavour (Arch, Raspbian, NOOBS, whatever)